# Why does 'now()'::timestamp return the current timestamp in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, timestamp

A simple example:

```
select 'now()'::timestamp;
```

gives

```
2016-03-12 07:52:46.1
```

Note the single quote around `now()` function call.

I think the `now()` function call is escaped by the single quote and the database should output just `now()`. But I tested this on Postgres 9.0 and 8.4 and the results are both `2016-03-12 07:52:46.1`.

The same thing happens when I explicitly insert `'now()'` (note the single quote) into a field which is of `timestamp` type.

But if no implicit conversion to `timestamp` applies, it will just output `'now()'`, for example:

```
select 'now()';
```

gives:

```
now()
```

And I noted such 'unescaping' only happens to `now`, as I tested call to other functions are correctly escaped by single quote.

I failed to find a reasonable explanation to this, can anyone please give some advice?

Comment: Interesting. Can you insert 'now()' into a text column and `select the_text::timestamp from the_table`, too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a special function of the [conversion from string to timestamp or date/time type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5829); the parentheses are superfluous, as it's not really a function call. I have a pretty strong suspicion that that particular value was added in order to serve as the special default value for timestamp columns.

Answer (score 2):

The *value* `'now()'::timestamp` is exactly the same as `'now'::timestamp` and subtly *different* from the *function* call `now()`.

[Details in the *current* manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE) Note in particular that these strings ...

> ... are simply notational shorthands that will be converted to
>   ordinary date/time values when read. (In particular, `now` and related
>   strings are converted to a specific time value as soon as they are read.)

Typically, you do ***not*** want to use the string as column default, which would result in a constant representing the moment in time when the command was executed ("early binding"). Use `now()::timestamp` or the standard SQL function `LOCALTIMESTAMP` to get the current local time (dynamically - "late binding").

In most cases `timestamptz` would be a better choice to begin with. So `now()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Details:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

You need to understand the difference between string literals or string constants and typed values.
[Start in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)